# vertica-python Error on COPY LOCAL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, vertica

I was using this code for **'COPY LOCAL'** in python on **Vertica 7.1**:

```
conn_info = {'host': '192.168.1.1', 'port': 5433, 'user': 'dbadmin', 'password': 'xxxxxx', 'database': 'db'}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)
cur = connection.cursor()
file_name="/tmp/tmp_file"
temp_file = open(file_name,"w")
temp_file .write(records)
temp_file.close()
os.system('gzip -cvf9 %s > %s.gz'%(file_name,file_name))
qr="copy tmp_table(int_id, int_timestamp, ... ) from local '%s' GZIP delimiter ';' RECORD TERMINATOR E'\\r' NULL  '\\N';"%(file_name+'.gz')
cur.execute(qr)
```

But i want to do same on **Vertica 9.0.1** now and i got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "collector_as.py", line 264, in
>
> ```
> cur.execute(qr)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vertica_python/vertica/cursor.py", line 126, in execute
>
> ```
> self.connection.process_message(self._message)
> ```
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vertica_python/vertica/connection.py", line 232, in process_message
>
> ```
> raise errors.MessageError("Unhandled message: {0}".format(message))
> ```
>
> MessageError: Unhandled message:

my vertica-python version:

```
pip freeze | grep vertica  -->  vertica-python==0.7.3
```

### ------------------------

**Also** i tried new vertica-db-client from [VERTICA](https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/) (vertica-client-9.0.1-4.x86_64.tar.gz)
my vertica-db-client version:

```
pip freeze | grep vertica  -->  vertica-db-client==9.0.1.4
```

and i got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "collector_as.py", line 265, in
>
> ```
> cur.execute(qr)
> ```
>
> NotSupportedError: COPY LOCAL is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using vertica-python to do a COPY command, you use the `cur.copy(...)` method.

The copy method of the cursor takes two arguments

1. The copy command
2. The file to be copied

Also, instead of `FROM LOCAL`, you use `FROM STDIN`.

```py
qr="copy tmp_table(int_id, int_timestamp, ... ) from STDIN GZIP delimiter ';' RECORD TERMINATOR E'\\r' NULL  '\\N';"
cur.copy(qr, file_name+'.gz')
```

If you were using vsql—for example—then your syntax using `FROM LOCAL` would be correct, but vertica-python basically takes the file given as the second argument and pipes it into the copy command as STDIN.