# vertica copy command works in vertica shell but not using vertica-python cursor

Tags: vertica

query = "COPY s_clids.o(cid,utype,uid,mid,aid,b,o,d,ad,adat,trid) FROM LOCAL '/database/clids/o.csv'  PARSER fcsvparser(header='true') DIRECT REJECTMAX 20000    EXCEPTIONS '/tmp/o_exception.csv' REJECTED DATA '/tmp/o_rejected.csv'"

this works fine in vsql shell but gets stuck when using python cursor.
im using vertica python

Comment: Are you using `cur.execute(query)` or `cur.copy(query)`. There was a similar question, that has already been answered regarding this same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061816/vertica-python-error-on-copy-local